# ctrlp only searching lines in ag.1.md file?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, macvim, ag, ctrlp

`:CtrlPBuffer<CR><c-d>` and `:CtrlPMRU<CR><c-d>` work normally, but when I use `:CtrlP<CR><c-d>`, the listing is always empty, and if I type `--` inside the prompt, it matches these lines:

```
>      --ackmate            Print results in AckMate-parseable format
>      --ignore PATTERN     Ignore files/directories matching PATTERN
>      --one-device         Don't follow links to other devices.
>      --[no]group          Same as --[no]break --[no]heading
>      --column             Print column numbers in results
>      --search-binary      Search binary files for matches
>      --stats-only         Print stats and nothing else.
> ag: unrecognized option `--hiden'
>   ag --list-file-types
>   ag --html needle
```

which appear to be in the_silver_searcher/doc/ag.1.md. I found the `--hiden` typo
in `let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor --hiden -g ""'` and fixed it, so now `:echo g:ctrlp_user_command` prints `ag %s -l --nocolor --hidden -g ""`, but it still gives the same results for `:CtrlPBuffer<CR><c-d>`

in my `.vimrc`:

```
    Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim', {'on': ['CtrlP', 'CtrlPMixed', 'CtrlPMRU']}
    Plugin 'FelikZ/ctrlp-py-matcher'
    ...
    let g:ctrlp_mruf_max = 20
    nnoremap <silent> <Space>f :CtrlP<CR><c-d>
    nnoremap <silent> <Space>F :CtrlP<CR>
    nnoremap <silent> <Space>b :CtrlPBuffer<CR><c-d>
    nnoremap <silent> <Space>r :CtrlPMRU<CR><c-d>
    let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 'c'
    ...
    let g:ctrlp_prompt_mappings = {
      \ 'CreateNewFile()':      ['<c-n>'],
      \ }

    let g:ctrlp_match_func = { 'match': 'pymatcher#PyMatch' }
    let g:ctrlp_lazy_update = 350
    let g:ctrlp_clear_cache_on_exit = 0
    let g:ctrlp_max_files = 0
    " If ag is available use it as filename list generator instead of 'find'
    if executable("ag")
        set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolor
        let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor --hidden -g ""'
    endif
```

in my `.bash_profile`:

```
    alias ag='ag --path-to-ignore ~/.ignore'
```

my global `.ignore`:

```
pyc
__pycache__/
git
tmp
swp
swo
```

my `.gitignore_global`:

```
*~
.DS_Store
.pyc
__pycache__/
```

my `.hgignore_global`:

```
syntax: glob

*~
.DS_Store
```

how do I fix this? is something wrong with my ignore files?

Answer (score 0):

sourcing the .vimrc file was not enough; I had to run `CtrlPClearCach` or `CtrlPClearAllCaches`, and `alias ag='ag -U --skip-vcs-ignores --path-to-ignore ~/.ignore'` in my `.bash_prifile` will use only the `.ignore` file.